# Parsing a custom config file in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to collapse a file that I am reading in PHP and generate configuration one liners that I can use elsewhere in my application. The PHP script I have pulls this file from a system which I can configure at a bash prompt using a `set` command.

For example, the commands

`set system ntp server 0.pool.ntp.org`
`set system ntp server 1.pool.ntp.org`
`set system ntp server 2.pool.ntp.org`

would generate this structure in the system's config file:

`system {
    ntp {
        server 0.pool.ntp.org {
        }
        server 1.pool.ntp.org {
        }
        server 2.pool.ntp.org {
        }
    }
}`

.. and I would like to have my PHP script read this file and generate the following output:

`system ntp server 0.pool.ntp.org`
`system ntp server 1.pool.ntp.org`
`system ntp server 2.pool.ntp.org`

I'm not sure how I would approach this, and am even having problems writing psudo-code to understand how I can collapse these nodes and generate my desired lines. What is making it tough for me is the fact that the depth of the configuration nodes can vary, for example:

`system login user root authentication encrypted-password <password>`

.. generates the structure ..

`system {
    login {
        user root {
            authentication {
                encrypted-password <password>
            }
        }
    }
}`

.. and merged with the NTP command above, the whole config file looks like:

`system {
    login {
        user root {
            authentication {
                encrypted-password <password>
            }
        }
    }
    ntp {
        server 0.pool.ntp.org {
        }
        server 1.pool.ntp.org {
        }
        server 2.pool.ntp.org {
        }
    }
}`

Are there any approaches that someone can suggest?

Comment: Do you have the option to switch to a more standard format?
Your current format is fairly close to a JSON and if you have access to the script that creates the config, you'll have many easy options.

Comment: How does the system know that `user root` is one key and not two separeate ones as in `{user {root ...`? Is there a list of allowed keys?

Answer (score 0):

1. Take the config file and create an array of it with each line is an item of the array
2. if one of those items has a `{` or `}` in it, split the item into two items so that at the end each of your brackets is an own item
3. create a function that creates an array with the following rule:

   - if the item is an opening bracket: create a new sub-array and put everything that followis in it
   - if the item is a closing bracket, terminate the sub-array and continue in the previous parent array
   - if neither, put it inside

with that little algorythm you should be able to cycle through your config and create the desired output you want. For example filter by `key` that matches to `ntp`. Be creative there :)